# How to remove the distance between columns?

Tags: html, css

How to remove the distance between these columns? That is, make the second column adjoin the element №2.

Without using two containers for the two columns (because the number and size of elements will change but they should be the most similar in height). Thus `max-height` of `body` is also not suitable.

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  column-count: 2;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" style="height:100px;width:80px">1</div>
<div class="item" style="height:80px;width:100px">2</div>
<div class="item" style="height:60px;width:60px">3</div>
<div class="item" style="height:100px;width:100px">4</div>
<div class="item" style="height:120px;width:120px">5</div>
```

Comment: the feature of columns design to have same width of columns. because you have in the second column wider div, the first column is also wider..

Comment: Yes, I understand. But maybe there is something to do with this - to make the column width individual according to the column content. Otherwise the `column-count` feature is "raw" for using.

Answer (score 0):

```
    body {
 
      border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .item {
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
 
    .wrappper {
    display:flex;
   }
<div class='wrappper'>
<div>
    <div class="item" style="height:100px;width:80px">1</div>
    <div class="item" style="height:80px;width:100px">2</div>
    <div class="item" style="height:60px;width:60px">3</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="item" style="height:100px;width:100px">4</div>
    <div class="item" style="height:120px;width:120px">5</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using two containers (for the two columns) is not suitable because the number and size of elements will change. So some general solution is needed.

Comment: this works for 2 columns no matter the size/number of columns elements: https://codepen.io/antekai/pen/WNvoVYq

Comment: But I don't know how many elements will be in a column. That is why the `column-count` property is good.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `column-rule: 0` and `column-gap: 0` will help but it's still going to be a little weird with the width of the surrounding inline-block container.

Flexbox would be an ideal way to go with a column flex-direction like so:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-width: 331px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 320px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    break-inside: avoid;
    flex-basis: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" style="height:100px;width:80px">1</div>
<div class="item" style="height:80px;width:100px">2</div>
<div class="item" style="height:60px;width:60px">3</div>
<div class="item" style="height:100px;width:100px">4</div>
<div class="item" style="height:120px;width:120px">5</div>
```

Comment: `max-height` is not suitable (as said in the question) because the number and size of elements are different at each time. Possible without concrete values (height/width)? Maybe with grid?

Comment: grid would not work because you need to know the number of rows for a css grid to work